# Error in train function of caret package (R language) - Invalid argument type: 'sim' & 'obs' have to be of class: c('integer', 'numeric', 'ts', 'zoo')

Tags: r, r-caret, knn

I am having a problem with the train function of the caret package (R Language). When running the following code:

```r
mdl <- train(m, data=in.train, method="knn", trControl = fitControl, maximize=FALSE, metric="MAE", na.action=na.omit)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "Invalid argument type: 'sim' & 'obs' have to be of class: c('integer', 'numeric', 'ts', 'zoo')"
```

If I am not mistaken this might be due to an error in the calculation of RMSE or R2 inside the train function. Do you have any ideas? I am sure my input data does not have any NAs values. I was wondering if the simulated data can have a NA value which might be causing the problem.

Here follows the tracking of the error:

```
10 stop(simpleError(msg, call = expr)) 

9 e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) 

8 foreach(iter = seq(along = resampleIndex), .combine = "c", .verbose = FALSE, 
    .packages = pkgs, .errorhandling = "stop") %:% foreach(parm = 1:nrow(info$loop), 
    .combine = "c", .verbose = FALSE, .packages = pkgs, .errorhandling = "stop") %op% 
    { ... 

7 nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo, 
    method = models, ppOpts = preProcess, ctrl = trControl, lev = classLevels, 
    ...) 

6 train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) 

5 train(x, y, weights = w, ...) 

4 train.formula(m, data = in.train, method = typeModel, preProcess = c("center", 
    "scale"), trControl = fitControl, maximize = FALSE, metric = "MAD", 
    na.action = na.omit)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you haven't input the right class of data - it is expecting `zoo` / timeseries (`ts`) class data and the function didn't get it.

Comment: According to the error, an inner function of train is expecting an integer, numeric, ts or zoo: I am sure my in.train is a numeric stream (I forced it with in.train <- in.train[,sapply(in.train,is.numeric)]). So I don't know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Basically knn fitted an intercept-only model. This resulted in constant-valued predictions and several RMSE NA values. Please note predictions with zero variance have undefined RMSE and R2.

After including new informative features to the model I was able to perform a cross-validation.

Similar errors:

> Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing:
>
> NA's :400 NA's :400